# PHP prepared statement - reset row pointer

Tags: php, sql, arrays, db2, reset

I have the below code, which the comments should clearly explain.  I want to query a file for given information, and then once the results are returned, add a field onto the resulting array.  Then, access the resulting array later in my program.

The problem with the code below is, i think the array is at the last record the second time i attempt to loop... and reset($stmt1) fails because $stmt1 is "not an array object"...

```
<?php 

$sql1 = "SELECT dpdpt, SUM(dpbir) FROM dwhlib.dwdptstr WHERE dpdpt < '312' GROUP BY dpdpt ";

//Setup connection
$conn_resource = db2_connect ( "*LOCAL", "", "" );

//Verify connection successful
if (! $conn_resource) {
    echo "Connection failed. SQL Err:";
    echo db2_conn_error ();
    echo "<br/>";
    echo db2_conn_errormsg ();
    exit ();
}

//Prepare the stmt
$stmt1 = db2_prepare ( $conn_resource, $sql1 );

//Execute the prepared statement
if (! db2_execute ( $stmt1 )) {
    echo 'The db2 execute failed. ';
    echo 'SQLSTATE value: ' . db2_stmt_error ();
    echo ' Message: ' . db2_stmt_errormsg ();
    exit ();
}

//Loop through all rows, adding a third field
while ( $row1 = &db2_fetch_array ( $stmt1 ) ) {
    $row1[2] = "TEST";
}

//Reset stmt or array back to first record
//??

//Print results
echo "<table border=1>";
while ( $row = db2_fetch_array ( $stmt1 ) ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.  But there's not really a compelling reason to try to do it that way anyway.

Keep it simple.  Just build an array the first time through.

```
$rows = array();
//Loop through all rows, adding a third field
while ( $row = db2_fetch_array ( $stmt1 ) ) {
    $row[2] = "TEST";
    $rows[] = $row;
}
db2_free_result($stmt1);

//Print results
echo "<table border=1>";
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This will, at worst, temporarily double your memory usage while the array is being built.